# Oracle ADF Insert operation set SQL Server database to use database auto increment PK

Tags: sql-server, oracle-adf

I am making a simple CRUD application using Oracle ADF with SQL Server database.
My problem is that when inserting a new record into SQL Server table, I get an error on the primary key. My table has a primary key as Auto_Increment, but ADF is having problems to respect the database to do its own Auto_increment how do you go about this. I am sure there is a simple solution that works but I cant find one.

Regards
Xavier

Comment: Please post the actual error. Is ADF providing the value or not? If it _is_, then your PK should _not_ be an `IDENTITY`. If it _is not_, then your PK _should_ be an IDENTITY.

Comment: "Attribute idbsctesttable in TestEO is required" in this case I assume that ADF is providing the value. but What I want is for the database to provide the value

Comment: The SQL Server database can provide the value by defining and Identity on the column. I don’t know how you make ADF honour that.

Comment: making ADF honour that - that is exactly what I am failing to do.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vuo594dkYiXpx1aYZHvaVdDd50oTFigO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ec67vQosqOHrmJUPannVejixgs11k5GO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c9_abOs-XyEspcswteEAR4UECXjGgHBu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the first file gives the error I am getting, the second gives the database configuration, and the third gives the attribute setup in ADF

Comment: The top of this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/multidatabaseapp-085183.html says: _Your database cannot contain any automatically-generated primary key columns (IDENTITY column in SQL Server). Instead, use ADF BC-generated unique ids for primary keys of this type_ Why are you using something like Oracle ADF with SQL Server? Why are you asking questions that can be googled?

Comment: Since your SQL Server screenshot doesn't show `IDENTITY`, I will assume you're not using it. So... go to the page I linked in the previous comment then read the section entitled "Set Up Primary Key Generation". Please make an effort to read documentation next time.

Comment: thanks for the way Forward, I have a system that was written with pure java and a SQL Server database and I would want to maintain that, I had a challenge to doing a web version of the same and I have tried PrimeFaces which did not impress at all but Oracle ADF gives me everything I need with a faster development time frame. Migrating to Oracle database would be a bit expensive for the project.

Comment: Did reading that solve your issue? If so it would be great if you could write it up in an answer.